# Angular 2 Search in array and select an item

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

In my app I fetch list of users from online web service and store it into an array of `fetchedUsers`. I am using model driven forms in Angular 2. I have an input text field which takes input from user. I have a working search pipe which takes input from text field and displays only matched data. I am trying to implement the search functionality same as [here](http://webkity.com/). I have tried to get this behaviour through some angular 2 plugins such as `ng2-select` but no luck. I do not want a select element which can search. I want an input field which can search and display matched data.

**Already Done :**

So far i can search and display matched data. if you type something for example `a` you can see the results below input field.

**Trying To Achieve:**

I want to navigate through the results using keyboard up and down keys and if user press enter key on an item i want that item to be added to array of `selectedUsers` and display contents of `selectedUsers` below.

Please help how to achieve this behaviour? For understanding you can visit the link mentioned above.

I have a working demo of my app [here](https://www.walana.org/search-select/) and code can be viewed on [github](https://github.com/usmanwalana/search-select)

Comment: sorry but your demo doesn't work fine, there is no user showing up...

Comment: So you want functionality commonly known as "autocomplete", right? Have you checked for example this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-auto-complete and plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/3pB1Gx?p=preview ?

Comment: @PetrAdam Thank you so much. I tested this plugin and its working.

Answer (score 0):

call a function on enter using `(keyup.enter)` and get the selected value.

```
<option #val (keyup.enter)="myFunction(val)"></option>
```